# How to load multiple files (same schema) into a table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a folder of csv files with the same schema that I want to load into a bigquery table.

Is there an option to give folder path as the input to BQ command to load into bigquery table? I'm interested to know if it can be done without iterating over the files or merging the input files at the source.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If using cloud storage is an option, you can put them all in a common prefix in a bucket and use a wildcard e.g. `gs://my_bucket/some/path/files*` to specify a single load job with multiple inputs quickly.

Comment: Thanks. That works. What if the files are inside subfolders? Can we set option to recursively load data from sub-folders as well?

Comment: GCS isn't a filesystem in that regard, the path is really only a key to the binary objects.  Put another way, it doesn't matter how many slashes are in the gs:// path as long as your string prefix will match only the CSV files you want.

Comment: Is it necessary to go through google cloud storage to upload lots of files (thousands of files)? I'm only seeing answers for using GCS but that's very indirect and maybe more expensive.

Answer (score 7):

Note that

> You can use only one wildcard for objects (filenames) within your bucket. The wildcard can appear inside the object name or at the end of the object name. Appending a wildcard to the bucket name is unsupported.

so something like `gs://my_bucket/some/*/files*` is not supported.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#load-wildcards

Answer (score 1):

The files can be in subdirectories, if you want to recursively include all CSV:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV \
dataset_name.table_name \
"gs://my_bucket/folder/*.csv"
```

This puts a wildcard on intermediate path and filename. (ex. * expands to `subfolder/folder2/filename`)