# Google BigQuery bulk load data into table

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I think that what I want to do is not feasible at the moment but want to clarify.

I have a bucket say `bucketA` with files served to the public and a bucket say `bucketB` where access logs of `bucketA` are stored in a specific CSV format

What I want to do is to run SQL queries to these access logs. The problem that I have is that the logs are stored in different CSVs (one per hour I think). I tried to import them through BigQuery UI interface but it seems that there is a one to one CSV to table mapping. When you define the input location the placeholder and documentation as you to put a `gs://<bucket_name>/<path_to_input_file>`.

Based on the above my question is: Is it possible to upload a all files in a bucket to a single BigQuery table, with something like an "*" asterisk operator?

Once the table is constructed what happens when more files with data get stored in the bucket? Do I need to re-run, is there a scheduler?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303333/how-to-load-multiple-files-same-schema-into-a-table-in-bigquery/42303869. Does that question (and answer) help?

Comment: They are very similar: (1) here we have a different (and more comprehensive) answer, (2) I ask something more specific user case in mind, perhaps there are or there will be alternative solutions. What is the optimal SO way to proceed?

Comment: Second comment: after a follow up, a different question might be constructed altogether.

Comment: You've edited your question, so I've updated my answer.

Comment: @GrahamPolley Perfect answer, cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I think we have a different question now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on the above my question is: Is it possible to upload a all
>   files in a bucket to a single BigQuery table, with something like an
>   "*" asterisk operator?

You can **query** them directly in GCS (federated source) or **load** then all into a native table using `*` in both cases:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Once the table is constructed what happens when more files with data get stored in the bucket? Do I need to re-run, is there a scheduler?

If you leave it as en `external` table, then each time you query BigQuery will scan all the files, so you'll get new files/data. If you load it as a native table, then you'll need to schedule a job yourself to append each new file to your table.

Comment: Just did it with "mixed" results. Your answer is correct. The problem that I had was that there were some 57 byte sized CSVs dropped in the bucket with a different header and contents than the rest. Is there any way to ignore them?

Comment: found it "_usage_" and "_storage_" in files

Comment: If my answer is "correct", then please accept it. Then create a new question for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Using BigQuery web UI, after I have created the new table + some initial data with the standard upload csv method.

For quick testing, how to use BigQuery web UI to insert more new data into the existing table?

I realized I CANNOT copy and paste multiple insert statements in the Query editor textbox.

```sql
INSERT INTO dataset.myschema VALUES ('new value1', 'more value1');
INSERT INTO dataset.myschema VALUES ('new value2', 'more value2');
```

Wow, then it will be tedious to insert new line of data 1 by 1.

Luckily BigQuery supports `INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows`.

```sql
INSERT INTO dataset.myschema VALUES ('new value1', 'more value1'),
('new value2', 'more value2');
```