# dplyr / bigrquery way of querying/binding multiple tables of the same schema in BigQuery?

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, dbplyr

Using the methods outlined in [this](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) readme doc, it's straight forward to query a single table, like so

```
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)

natality <- tbl(con, "natality")

natality %>%
  select(year, month, day, weight_pounds) %>% 
  head(10) %>%
  collect()
```

This allows us to write regular `dplyr` code against `natality`, and `bigrquery` translates that `dplyr` code into a BigQuery query.

But suppose the `natality` table was instead 2 (or more) separate tables named `natality1`, `natality2`, and that they could be `rbind`'d together.

How can I do this using BigQuery? That is, how can I query these separate tables as though they are all together as one table?

#### What I tried

I thought `bind_rows` may work, but it doesn't.

```
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)

natality1 <- tbl(con, "natality1")
natality2 <- tbl(con, "natality2")

natality1 %>% bind_rows(., natality2) %>%
  select(year, month, day, weight_pounds) %>% 
  head(10) %>%
  collect()
```

#### Notes

- A scan of the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/bigrquery.pdf) didn't reveal anything obvious (but there maybe something).
- BigQuery [supports wildcard for selecting/moving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303333/how-to-load-multiple-files-same-schema-into-a-table-in-bigquery). I'm not sure if that support extends into BigQuery and bigrquery

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of `dbplyr` having `rbind` functionality. Perhaps because not every database backend supports it?

The way I solve this problem in SQL Server is with a custom function that writes an explicit `UNION ALL` query (the SQL Server equivalent of `rbind`). Below is an example function for SQL ([link to other functions from this approach](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers/blob/master/utility_functions.r)). Perhaps this example can serve as inspiration for an equivalent `bigquery` approach?

```
union_all = function(table_a,table_b){
  # extract the connection
  db_connection = table_a$src$con

  sql_query = build_sql(con = db_connection,
                      sql_render(table_a), # the SQL code that defines table A
                      "\nUNION ALL\n", # insert union all command between them
                      sql_render(table_b) # the SQL code that defines table B
  )

  return(tbl(db_connection, sql(sql_query)))
}
```

The idea is that `union_all()` returns a remote table object defined by a query with the `rbind` equivalent command within it.

Comment: It turns out I was 'doing it wrong'. Rather than moving multiple parts of a single table into BigQuery, I should have first combined them (while in Storage) - and only then moved moved the single table in BigQuery. I really appreciate your help (your solution is a very creative workaround)

Comment: Glad to hear you've found a solution. Perhaps you could post it as the correct answer?