# When batch loading CSVs from GCS to BigQuery, is the table data viewable incrementally, or only once all files are loaded?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking to load CSV data from Google Cloud Storage to a BigQuery table (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv)) as a batch (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data)) using wildcards, and was wondering whether:

1. The data in the table will only be available once *all* CSVs have been loaded (i.e the files get collated in some way *before* being loaded into BigQuery)
2. The data in the table will be updated *incrementally* with each CSV that's loaded (i.e. each CSV is loaded separately, as a separate job)

For some context, I'm trying to work out if it will be possible for a user to view incomplete table data if they access the table before the job to load the batch of CSVs has finished.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303333/how-to-load-multiple-files-same-schema-into-a-table-in-bigquery) before, but I don't have enough reputation to comment :'(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data are viewable when the job is completed, therefore after all the files ingested.

Indeed, when you define a job, you can specify a WriteTruncate disposition. That means all the current data will be replaced by the new one. If the job fails, the current data stay unchanged. That behaviour won't be possible in case of incremental load.

If you want to propose incremental load, you can use a not efficient process: read the file with dataflow and stream the content into BigQuery. this time, the users will be able to view the incremental data by requesting them (not with the preview feature in the Console, because the streamed data stayed for a while in the buffer of BigQuery (max 90 minutes))